# Is there a way to preserve full stratum names in svydescribe command?

Tags: stata

In Stata, I'm trying to describe a variable in relation to its stratum (if that makes sense) but the name of the stratum keeps being shortened.

I have used `svydescribe` but it keeps shortening it and since some of the strata (which are regions in this case) have the same first part but different second parts, it's not very informative.

The regions are supposed to look something like this:

[tab (recoded) region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ1eW.png)

But when I use `svydescribe`, it shows up like this:

[svydescribe region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCUsf.png)

*region is colored red in the data editor - str23
*(recoded) region has a black font - long

Is there a way to stop the command from shortening it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I only have access to Stata 14, so I don't know whether this continues to be a problem in newer versions of Stata. The source code of `svydescribe` in my version is such that all columns are truncated to 8 characters, so you would have to change the ado file (create a backup!). (My version of `svydescribe` is `version 2.4.2  20feb2015`; check the first line of the window that opens when you type `view svydescribe.ado, adopath`.)

Changing the source file is prone to errors, so I would suggest that you recode your stratum variable to a shorter string such as the NUTS1 (now ITL 1) codes for the UK and NUTS0 for Ireland, so `English-London` would become `TLI`.

Comment: In Stata 18 as in 14 the code is quite long but I see no reason to change the advice from a quick glance at what it does. Rewriting this command would not be trivial. The advice in the last paragraph here is most practical.